# Replacement pattern for an anonymous class in Dart

Tags: design-patterns, dart, anonymous-class

I'm trying to build a base class Table< T > that uses a list TableColumns< T > to display a table in Dart. In Java this would be done with an anonymous class pattern where a leaf class would look as simple a the following:

```
class PartTable extends Table< Part > {

  // Column 1: Part Number


  addColumn( new TableColumn<Part>("Part Number") {

    String get(Part part) { part.getNumber().toString() }

    void set(Part part, String number) {
      part.setNumber(number);
    }
  });

  // Column 2: Part Description

  addColumn( new TableColumn<Part>("Part Description") {

    String get(Part part) { part.getDescription().toString() }

    void set(Part part, String desc) {
      part.setDescription(desc);
    }
  });

}
```

Can anybody suggest a Dart design pattern that would nicely substitute for the Java Anonymous Class pattern above? The basic idea is that the anonymous TableColumn class abstract methods (e.g. get and set) are overridden by the by anonymous class in the Table constructor to provide the view specific overrides for working with a part's attributes. Thus the Table can have an arbitrary number of columns, and provide view specific CRUD behavior for each parts attributes in the tables cell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a general answer for your question. It really depends on your code. You can ever create a class for all anonymous class or refactor your API and try to avoid them.

For instance your sample code could be refactored to use functions to define `get`/`set` :

```dart
final table = new Table<Part>()
    ..addColumn(new Column<Part>(
        "Part Number", 
        (p) => p.number.toString(),
        (p, s) => p.number = s))
    ..addColumn(new Column<Part>(
        "Part Description", 
        (p) => p.desc.toString(), 
        (p, s) => p.desc = s));
```

Here's what the underlying code could be :

```dart
typedef String ColumnGetter<T>(T t);

typedef void ColumnSetter<T>(T t, String s);

class Column<T> {
  final String name;
  final ColumnGetter<T> get;
  final ColumnSetter<T> set;
  Column(this.name, this.get, this.set);
}

class Table<T> {
  List<T> _elements;
  final _columns = [];
  void addColumn(Column<T> column) => _columns.add(column);
  void set elements(List<T> elements) {
    this._elements = elements;
    // updateDisplay
  }
}
```